# Is there a way to have an ai characters ask my questions so that a player can choose, leading to different story lines?

Tags: unity

Character asks "Do you choose A or B?". Player chooses "B" . Story line changes based exclusively on the conversation.

Comment: Yes any game is possible with unity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can do this by storing the result of the player's choice in some fashion.

If your game is basically a simple branching conversation, you can simply implement the entire dialog as some kind of [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) or [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)) structure, where the current gameplay state is represented by a reference to that current node in the tree. Each response is associated with an edge to another node; when the player chooses that response you advance the state reference to the node at the end of that response's edge.

Most games don't consist *entirely* of branching conversation trees though. So a more common, generalized approach is to create a system of "stuff done flags," or "progress bits." A set of booleans (or other types, if you get fancy) that represent actions the player has taken. A very simple implementation can be a big array of booleans, which each index in the array associated with a particular event or action:

```
enum StuffDoneLabels {
  TalkedToTheSheriff,
  FoundMagicRing,
  ToldTheOgressSheWasUgly,
  KilledTheOgress,
  LootedTheOgressTreasureCave,
};
```

You can then associate dialog responses with a flag, or set of flags, that they set or clear when that dialog response is taken (for example, telling the evil ogress that she isn't very pretty). You can also have systems to set these flags when you pick up items, discover or enter areas, et cetera.

Then, elsewhere, you can check the state of various flags to see if actions should be taken. Perhaps if the player enters a specific cave, the game checks to see if you killed the ogress and if so spawns her sister in to take revenge.